# flutter Firebase Messaging and sqflite

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I try to send a message from my website to users with `Firebase` and store the message in the user device with `sqflite` plugin.

When the application in the foreground, everything works good and message insert in the database. But when the application in the background or completely close it just displays notification and data not inserted in the database.

**edit:**

After setting `click_action` for notification, Clicking on the notification data will be saved but if the user dismisses notification data lost.

**code**

```
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

@override
void initState() {
    prepareFirebaseCloudMessaging();
    super.initState();
 }
void prepareFirebaseCloudMessaging() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) IOSPermission();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        notificationDataHandler(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        notificationDataHandler(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        notificationDataHandler(message);
      },
    );
  }

void notificationDataHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    try {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'MY_DATABASE_FILE.db');
    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE Messages (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, message TEXT, date TEXT, seen INTEGER)');
    });
    Message messageStore = Message(
        null, message["data"]["message"], message["data"]["date"], false);
      await database.insert("Messages", messageStore.toMap());
    database.close();
    }catch(e){
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Were did use placesd this code? on a UI page?

Comment: @user8773560 in my `HomePageScreen` wdiget

Comment: You can't place it there. Because once application is closed or in background, this code will be killed. You need to  use Services. Take a look at https://medium.com/flutter-io/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124

Comment: @user8773560 It's not true because if set `click_action` for notification and user clicks on the notification, data send to `onLaunch` method `configure`. but if the user does not click on notification data lost.